# CNN training and overfitting

Tags: validation, overfitting, conv-neural-network, computer-vision

When testing the training of a CNN code with a small data set (approx 2560 images each for training and validation), what is over-fitting and how can it be mitigated? 
Arnold

Comment: So you have a small set of photos, say 3000, labeled of cats and dogs.  Most of your cat photos happen to be orange tabbies.  So you train on the toy data, and your model says "I know a cat when I see one!" (high training accuracy) and then you give it a photo of an orange dog, and it thinks it's a cat.  Your model was memorizing features (orangeness) from the training set and overfitting on it.  Using a larger data set (more -- and more varied -- photos) and adding dropout layers will help.